# why does line_chart in Chartkick has to show time on a date data?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chartkick

I'ved got a line chart like this with date data (not including time)

```
 new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-2", {"2013-02-10": 11, "2013-02-11": 6});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yekLh/1/

why does chartkick always have to include time ? 
how do i show the series in dates only ?

Comment: As I understand it, ChartKick uses the Google Visualization API for the actual charts, which will display tick marks for dates based on the range of values presented to the chart.  I suspect that in your case, ChartKick is translating your date strings into Date objects, which is why you see this behavior.  I don't know how to change ChartKick's behavior, but I know you can get the customization you need if you skip the middleman API and just use the [Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer, with discrete and hAxis,

http://jsfiddle.net/yekLh/5/

```
new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-2", 
 {"2013-02-10": 11, "2013-02-11": 6, "2013-02-12": 12, "2013-02-13": 5}, 
{"library":
        {title: "Company Performance",
        "hAxis":{"title":"Date","gridlines":
            {"count":3,"color":"#CCC"},"format":"dd/MM/yy"}}, 
        "discrete": true});
```

Comment: Hi @Axil, say the time is being displayed at the tooltip alone, is it possible to just customise the tooltip alone and not utilise discrete to be true in this case? Thanks!